# Is there any way to export & import the data from ActiveMQ leveldb store ?

Tags: import, export, activemq-classic, leveldb

If yes, Please provide the steps for export & import the data from ActiveMQ.
We are using the ActiveMQ 5.8.0 in Linux Environment...

Thanks in Advance....

Answer (score 3):

Apache ActiveMQ does not have any such tool. But if you use the leveldb store, you can look for leveldb tooling.

Mind that leveldb in 5.8 is **not** so good, you should consider updating to a later release where leveldb has been hardened much more.